# Can not attach input text box to an angular $scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have some markup in my angular app that looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr ng-repeat="query in saved_queries">
    <td ng-click="fill()"><a>{{ query.title || query.query_string }}</a></td>
    <td class="pull-right" ng-click="kill_entry({{query.id}})"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></td>
    <td class="pull-right"><input ng-model="title_box" name="title_box" id="title_box"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" ng-click="add_title({{query.id}})"></i></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The idea here is that a table lists out all of the available saved queries, and if you want to add a title to the query, you can use an input field, and when you click the edit icon it will change to display the title you just created.

It does this using an ng-click that runs this code:

```
 $scope.add_title = function(id){
    var title = $.post('http://10.241.16.159:3000/api/add_title', {'id': id, 'title': $scope.title_box });
    title.done(function(result){
      $('#refresh').click();
    })
 }
```

Currently, when I attempt to add titles using this form, I get these logs on the server:

```
Started POST "/api/add_title" for 172.25.82.141 at 2014-08-01 21:13:58 +0000
Processing by SavedQueriesController#update as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"43"}
```

The problem is, the Parameters hash SHOULD look like this

```
{"id"=>"43", "title"=>"input from text box"}
```

For whatever reason, the input from the text box is not being passed to the server. $scope.title_box must not be taking on the correct value.

Comment: first thing kindly remove "</input>" input is self closing tag

Comment: $http.post instead of "$.post" would be the better angular way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding each `query in saved_queries` to the same `ng-model="title_box"`.

It looks like you should bind the inputs to `query.title_box` instead.  Then, pass the entire `query` object to your click handler.

```
<input ng-model="query.title_box" name="title_box" id="title_box" />
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" ng-click="add_title(query)"></i>
```

Here is a working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/mkH4IwBbL3Svi8CjkERC?p=preview